# How to configure dojox.cometd for callback-polling?

Tags: callback, dojo, polling, cometd

So far I found some examples on how to configure dojox.cometd, but none of them configure the connectionType. I am currently more interested in callback-polling instead of the long-polling (that is the default one, as far as I know).

Somebody can help me here? I must admit that the dojox documentation is quite obscure for me, and even the source code is kind of obfuscated (at least to me, I am no a javascript-ninja coder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured out that dojo is smart enough to activate the callback-polling looking at the url requested.